# Is there a way to get "Tonight" out of NSDateFormatter using doesRelativeDateFormatting?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm currently getting: "Today at 7:30 PM", but that doesn't really flow the way I'd like it to. Instead, I'd like to get "Tonight at 7:30 PM".

Here is some code:

```
let relativeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

relativeFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

relativeFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

let relativeString = relativeFormatter.stringFromDate(dates[index])

let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

let timeString = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(dates[index])

row.label2.setText(relativeString + " at " + timeString)
```

Does anybody know if this is built in to Swift?